# Custom Entry Template

Tags: cognito-forms

Do you get charged $.50 for using a custom .pdf template for entries?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Yes, if you have a custom template set up for your Document Merge then you will be charged $0.50 when on the Pro plan for each new entry you create a custom document merge with.

You can learn more about the [Document Merge feature](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/69/document-merging/customizing-documents), and our [pricing](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing) on our corresponding help content pages.

Answer (score 0):

The pricing for custom document merges templates has changed as of an announcement by Cognito posted on August 29, 2017.

The new pricing structure is a simple $4 per template with no limit on entries/documents created.

You can see more here:  https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/69/document-merging/customizing-documents#pricing